# Biopython after install

Tags: python, numpy

Hello everyone I am trying to use biopython in mac at python2.7.
I think I successfully installed Biopython because when I tested it by 
typing `import Bio`

no output but when i typing `from Bio.seq import seq`

it error.

```
from Bio.seq import seq
>>> import Bio
>>> from Bio.seq import seq
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named seq
>>>
```

I think my path is not wrong because when I entered import Bio it work.

is there anyone who know the possible reason??

my path is

```
gwagjunseong-ui-MacBook-Pro:~ warren$ echo $PATH
    /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/ncbi/blast/bin
```

and i installed `numpy` and tested it

but it make error

```
gwagjunseong-ui-MacBook-Pro:~ warren$ python -c 'import numpy ; numpy.test();'
Running unit tests for numpy
NumPy version 1.10.1
NumPy relaxed strides checking option: True
NumPy is installed in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy
Python version 2.7.10 (default, Oct 17 2015, 23:05:16) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)]
nose version 1.3.7
......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................S.........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................K................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................K...SK.S.......S...................................................................................clang: warning: -Wl,-rpath=/var/folders/v5/r7mmsbgj5gx7dll0gh_dx9j80000gn/T/tmpQMBhw4/libbar.so: 'linker' input unused
...SS................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................S..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................S......................................................................................................................S.....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_scripts.test_f2py
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/testing/decorators.py", line 146, in skipper_func
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/tests/test_scripts.py", line 68, in test_f2py
    code, stdout, stderr = run_command([f2py_cmd, '-v'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/tests/test_scripts.py", line 48, in run_command
    proc = Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

is there anyone know the reason?

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem in `numpy` installation. Python language is case sensitive:

```
from Bio.Seq import Seq
```

[Seq](http://biopython.org/wiki/Seq) is Caps.

```
>>> from Bio.Seq import Seq
>>> from Bio.Alphabet import generic_dna, generic_protein
>>> my_seq = Seq("AGTACACTGGT")
>>> my_seq
Seq('AGTACACTGGT', Alphabet())
>>> my_dna = Seq("AGTACACTGGT", generic_dna)
>>> my_dna
Seq('AGTACACTGGT', DNAAlphabet())
>>> my_protein = Seq("AGTACACTGGT", generic_protein)
>>> my_protein
Seq('AGTACACTGGT', ProteinAlphabet())
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!!!!  I was very fool ㅠ.ㅠ now it is working perfectly!!!